# Getting index of Linear Layouts using appium

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium, selendroid

I am having LinearLayouts. So I want index of those Linear Layouts which have content-desc as "product-list".

So what I did was :

```
 List<WebElement> allIdsOnCurrentScreen = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='android.widget.LinearLayout']"));
 for(int i=0;i<allIdsOnCurrentScreen.size();i++){
        if(allIdsOnCurrentScreen.get(i).getAttribute("name").toString()=="product_list")
            System.out.println(allIdsOnCurrentScreen.get(i).getAttribute("index"));
    }
```

But am not able to get index like this :

```
System.out.println(allIdsOnCurrentScreen.get(i).getAttribute("index"));
```

How to do it ? I want index for the Linear Layouts that are currently visible on screen with content-desc 'product_list';

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot read the 'index' attribute by appium, it's a framework limitation. For now at least.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using attribute "name" please use "content-desc" and run it again.